# How to interpret injury rates published in a sports medicine journal?

Tags: statistics, injury, sports

In the following article abstract: [200-400m breaststroke event dominate among knee overuse injuries in elite swimming athletes](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19085772/) the authors indicate

> Overuse injuries (0.22 / 1000 h) were more frequent than acute injuries (0.17 / 1000 h),

and

> Knee pain was predominant (0.17 / 1000 h) followed by shoulder overuse injuries (0.11 / 1000 h).

From someone outside the medical and sports medicine field, how are these rates of incidence (e.g. knee pain = 0.17 / 1000h) to be interpreted? Are there implied units associated with the first number? What is the convention at play and how far (i.e. beyond sports medicine) does that convention go?

Comment: The simplest way to find out what things like this in an abstract mean is to look for the full article. The article will spell out what the abbreviations and units of measure are. In this case, there's a link on the abstract that leads to the full article, and it's free.

Comment: In addition - if you ever see a rate of any sort, it will always have the subject of the rate as the numerator, and the "per unit" as denominator. An example might be speed (or velocity depending on how nit-picky you want to be) miles (subject) per hour (unit) (written as mi/h) or kilometres per hour (km/h) depending on your system of measurement.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you for the reply. All the links I see to the full article are to the Thieme e-journals and behind a paywall. Can you elaborate where you found a visible article version?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. It's not the full article but it includes a summary that spells out the abbreviations and measurements. https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-2008-1027987